# AngularJS - Hide the middle of navigation bar

Tags: angularjs

I have a navigation bar(ng-repeat) like picture shows blow. How can I replace the middle part with ellipsis when it's too long? I'm trying to watch the length of the array in controller, once there are more than 5 items in the array, should I manipulate the array(replace the content with string '...'?) or do something else?

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        return $rootScope.subNav.length;
    }, function() {
        if($rootScope.subNav.length >= 5) {
            //do something to replace middle with ...
        }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: I'm kinda confused by the question, sorry.  What do you mean should you manipulate the array? Also why do you have array on the rootScope, you should try to keep things off rootScope.

Comment: I'm using rootscope because this navbar is on index page, there are many ng-view pages which can change the array.  I don't know if I have to replace the items in array `$rootScope.subNav` with '...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way which is easier to hide the middle and append the ellipsis. No need to create another array, just use $index with ng-if and ng-show, here is the code:

```
<li ng-repeat="y in subNav" ng-if="$index <= 1 || $index >= subNav.length - 2">
    <a>{{y.name}}</a>
    <a ng-show="$index == 1 && subNav.length >= 5">...</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a separate array, for example visibleSubNav, and cunstruct it based on your subNav array.

```
if($rootScope.subNav.length >= 5) {
     $rootScope.visibleSubNav = $rootScope.subNav.slice(0,3);
     $rootScope.visibleSubNav.push('...');
     $rootScope.visibleSubNav.push($rootScope.subNav.slice(-1));
} else {
     $rootScope.visibleSubNav = $rootScope.subNav
}
```

Then use this constructed array in your template instead of original one.